# How does module.exports = mongoose; work when requiring "./database"?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mern

I'm a MERN stack beginner. I came across this snippet of code from a basic CRUD and I know that it works, but I don't get how.

```
//in server.js
const database = require('./database');

//in database.js
const mongoose = require('mongoose'); //importing mongoose
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/monguse', {useNewUrlParser:true}) //connected to db
    .then((db)=>{console.log('Database connected')}) //message if ok
    .catch((err) =>{console.log(`Database connection error: ${err}`)}); //catching errors

module.exports = mongoose;
```

I understand what is going on in database.js (It is my own version), but why does it work without using any method in server.js? It appears to make the connection only from using the "require" function. then in my routes there is no mention of that again; just using mongoose models in the requests.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In **database.js** you create an instance of the database and export it by name mongoose, and in **server.js** you are importing that instance of the mongoDB by name **database**.

Comment: Yes, I get that, but the connection to my database is made when importing? Like if that import were execute at the same time?

Comment: which import?  First server.js file executes by node than only other files are executed.

Comment: 'Require ('./database')'; does it make the connection to mongodb by itself? Only by referencing my mongoose obj from database.js?